# Cross-Origin Request Blocked With Axios React.js

Tags: node.js, reactjs, axios, cors

I know its an old question, but I dont know how to fix this. I call API request from local machine to a cloud server. I tried it yesterday and before and its works fine. But today when I try it, it return CORS error. Server side is using nodejs with express js for its framework. I have install cors  with `npm install cors` and use it in the index.js.

This is the error stack from mozilla :

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://appbk.myweb.com/api/v1/user/. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed).
```

This my index.js

```
const express       = require('express');
const bodyParser    = require('body-parser');
const cors          = require('cors')

app.use(cors());
```

This is my request with axios

```
function createHeader() {
    var timestamp = createTimestamp();
    var signature = createSignature(timestamp);

    const headers = {
        "id"            : id,
        "time"          : timestamp,
        "token"         : signature,
        "Content-Type"  : "application/json",
    };
    return headers;
}

export async function getUserList() {
    var response = await Axios.get(baseUrl + "user/", {headers: createHeader()})
    return response.data.data;
}
```

Quite confused because yesterday it works fine, and I dont change any code at all. Thank you.

Comment: The error message you quoted mentions `https://appbk.myweb.com/api/v1/banner/all/` but the call to `Axios.get` uses a URL that ends with `user/`. You're not telling us everything...

Comment: @jub0bs ah my bad, I pasted the wrong URL, thx for reminding me

Answer (score -1):

enable pre-flight request

```
app.options('*',cors());
```

Comment: Its still give the same error. Thank you for answering.